# That is very respectful of you

Tags: questions

"That is very respectful of you" - I am trying to tell someone that I really appreciate their action that is the fact of showing respect to someone. Would it be correct to frame the statement this way?

Comment: It's not in [the top ten list of attributes referenced by such contexts,](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is+very+*+of+you&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) but syntactically it's fine.

Answer (score 4):

There's no error in the English grammar.

It is a rather odd thing to say. It seems a little *patronising*. Why do you get to judge that something is respectful?  Perhaps if you are telling your son/daughter, or if you are a teacher of a young child.  But if you are talking to another adult, it would be odd. "That was very kind/thoughtful/good" are more common, and so more acceptable.